# add multiple horizontal buttons to table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've tried a bunch of stuff - adding a button from the object browser, changing attributes, searching the web, but no luck.  Essentially, I'd like to do --in the storyboard--: [image: pin screenshoot]

where you see "add to contacts" "share location" and "add to bookmarks".

Comment: I realize that I'd like to be able to do this in the storyboard as it's a graphical thing.  I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605381/how-to-add-a-footer-to-a-uitableview-in-storyboard) but the background is white - I'd like the table background (grey vertical stripes) to come through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the three buttons in a UIView that is 320 pixels wide and say 60 hight, and make that view the footer of your table.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a `UITableViewCell` whose `contentView` holds 3 separate `UIButtons`.
To do this programmatically, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` data source method, you can use code similar to the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* identifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIButton* button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIButton* button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        UIButton* button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button1.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(cell.contentView.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 250)); 
        button2.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(cell.contentView.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 125, 0, 125)); 
        button3.frame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(cell.contentView.bounds, UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 250, 0, 0)); 
        button1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        button2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        button3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Also, in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:` method of your delegate, do the following to have the default decoration of the cell totally disappear:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

You should obtain a result very similar to what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The `UITableView` is styled using the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` stye.
The three `UIButtons` are programmatically added to the `tableView.tableFooterView`.
Alternatively, you can add three `UIButtons` to  the `contentView` of the last `cell`.

Add buttons like:

```
UIButton *theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
theButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 40); 
[theButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:theButton];
```

Get the button positions correctly using trial and error :)