# Add footer to UITableViewController using storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard

So I try to add a footer to my table. And below is what I did, but the view doesn't go to the bottom of the app, instead, it will stay under the last TableCell. So how can I make it my footer for my page?

[image]

Comment: How do you want it to behave? The footer stays at the bottom of your table.

Comment: If you want a view always at the bottom of the screen then that isn't a table footer.

Comment: I want it to be the footer of the page. Sorry if I'm not so clear before!

Comment: Simply drag and drop UIView , check my answer.

Comment: Already have nice solution of this issue
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9605810/5711700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Footer in tableView Simply drag a UIView after the `UITableViewCell`.
For Header drag and drop a `UIView` into the header part.

`TableView` default taken it as a header View and footer
Connect an IBoutlet to the view and return the view in the delegate method.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return yourView;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, but instead of having that as a footer of my app, it becomes the footer of my table!!!